# Java out of date? installed version 8 JSE. Applets fail to work. Web check OK

Tags: java, applet

I continue to get out of date message when trying to view an applet.  The applet checker informs me that I have the correct version.  I have the security settings correct but still no joy.  When trying to go through the update it stops TO inform me that I have a later version already installed, which is correct.  On a Mac OS 10.9  I could show you the screen shot but don't have the points. Bugger

Thanks for those who have replied and I'll try to elaborate further.
JavaApplets do run from the java web site.  The creation of my own applets don't run.  I have done some research and it would seem that under version 8 all JApplets must be signed.  This would explain the message I receive.   Also the link below may explain what the problem is. Sorry but I don't have the 10 points yet to be able to send a screen shot.

Again runnin the update (version7 downloads) stops to inform me that I have a later version installed (version 8).  So you can see that things arn't perfect

![][1]

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2014/01/16/still-using-applets-sign-them-or-else

Comment: Could your title just be: "Applet fails to load after Java8 update"? You could elaborate in your question as to what you did and why it has happened.

Comment: "An applet". Did you try any other applet? For all we know its the applet itself which is buggered.

Comment: And you should really post the errors that your Applets throw when they fail.